# I have to determine whether a set of vectors is a spanning set of R^2

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having a bit of a struggle with this problem.

I am given these sets of vectors

\begin{array} { l } { \text { (a) } \{ u - v , v - w , 2 w - 2 u \} } \\ { \text { (b) } \{ u - v , v - w , 3 w - 3 u , u - v - w \} } \\ { \text { (c) } \{ u + v , - v - w , w + u \} } \\ { \text { (d) } \{ 2 u + 3 v + w , u - v - 2 w , 2 u + v - w \} } \\ { \text { (e) } \{ 2 u + 3 v + w , u - v + 2 w , 2 u + v - w \} } \end{array}

And I have to determine which ones are a spanning set for $\mathbb { R } ^ { 3 }$. For the first three it was simple, I put them in a column matrix and found that the third one is a combination of the first two. But I'm stuck at (d). I know the set is linearly dependent.

Comment: You need three linearly independent vectors to span $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: So, since the set is not linearly independent, it's not a spanning set?

Comment: It's also important to take the dimension of the vector space into account.  The family of vectors $\Bbb F v$ will span the one-dimensional vector space $\Bbb F v$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $u,v,w$ are linearly independent vectors of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. A set spans $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ if you can make $u,v$ and $w$ by linear combinations. For (b) note that
$$w=(u-v)-(u-v-w),\ v=(v-w)+w\text{ and }u=(u-v)+v$$
so (b) gives a spanning set.

For (c) we find
$$u=\frac{1}{2}((u+v)+(w+u)+(-v-w)),\ v=(u+v)-u\text{ and }w=(w+u)-u$$
so (c) is a spanning set.

You can do similar things for (d) and (e). Alternatively, if you have already seen this you can take the vectors as rows in a matrix and work out the row echelon form. If you have three pivots then the set is a spanning set.

Comment: Question, how exactly would I put the vectors? Would it be a column matrix or 3x2?

Comment: As an example for (b) you would use $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & -1\\ -3 & 0 & 3\\ 1 & -1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Okay, thank you!